# Align two DIVs in a TH

Tags: html, css

I have a `table` in which I want to add sort icons to the right of the text in the `th`. Here is my current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4zhg76nr/

The issue I am having is that when the columns are reduced in size due to resolution/browser window size, the text in the `th` gets moved above the icons. How can i use CSS to always have the text to the left of the icons?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I apologize for linking to a working example that displays the exact issue that I am experiencing. The code has been inserted here, so now it is in two places instead of one.

Comment: We don't want **links** for the reasons I stated..with your rep you should know this already. Code should be **in the question**...that's basic and a stated requirement,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap text and icon into `flex-container` and use `flexbox`

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="label">
    Order Number
  </div>
  <div class="sort-icons">
    <cfoutput>
      <div>
        <a href="?sortBy=OrderNumber&sortOrder=ASC" title="Sort Ascending"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="?sortBy=OrderNumber&sortOrder=DESC" title="Sort Descending"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" style="display: block;"></span></a>
      </div>
    </cfoutput>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zhg76nr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline-block; to the .sortable in the css

Answer (score 0):

You could define a max width and a float for each element so that they wont stack:

```
.sortable .label {
  display: inline;
  max-width:70%;  
  float:left;
  height: 39px;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.sortable .sort-icons {
  max-width:30%;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  height: 39px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change like This:**

```
.sortable .label {
  display: inline;<------Change to inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.3em;<--------Remove
  width:85%;<------------Added
  float:left;<-----------Added
  height: 39px;

}

.sortable .sort-icons {
  float: right;<--------Remove
  display: inline;<------Change to inline-block;
  width: 15%;<------Added
  vertical-align: top;<----Added
  height: 39px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4zhg76nr/3/)